# Creating a vector different double pointers to charecters c++

Tags: c++

Each time i go to add a new 'temp' board onto the vector it changes all of the previous ones to the one i just added so in the end i have a vector of identical temp variables ... why is this?

After ChangeBoard() is called, board is then updated (board is declared as char**, not with 'new').

```
char** temp;
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){

  ChangeBoard(); //makes changes to board

  temp = board; //sets temp to the latest version of the board

  vector.push_back(temp); //add temp to vector 
}
```

how do i make it so each 'temp' board is different in the vector?

do i need to declare temp as 'new' and then delete it after each time I add it on the vector.. if so how?

Thanks for any help on this!!

Comment: So you add multiple pointers to the same board and ask why changing of this one board changes ... this one board?

Comment: Well you need to copy `board` and to do that you need the size of board. And the memory for board has to be allocated somewhere if not new or malloc then as a literal or a static object.

Comment: @FredOverflow apparently named `vector` , adding to the convolution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confused copying pointers with copying memory.

It looks like you are updating the same memory pointed to by `board` over and over again, under the mistaken assumption that the `temp` assignment and/or the `vector.push_back(temp)` will copy all of the memory.  It does not, it merely adds another pointer to the same memory to the vector.

If `board` is not being allocated every time `ChangeBoard()` is called, then it is not a new board, it is the same memory being updated with new information.

If you want a pointer to a different board in every place in the vector, you need to allocate new memory that `board` points to every time you call `ChangeBoard()`.  (This probably makes `temp` unnecessary as well).